# How to check if bootstrap checkbox is checked in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get around the way to check if a checkbox is checked inside on a React.js component, and then store that in a Firebase Realtime database.

Right now, my checkbox works fine after 3 clics. I `console.log(this.state.isChecked);` and the first 2 clicks return "false" in my console, i can't understand why... Then after that if i continue clicking it works fine and alternate `true` and `false`.

Here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Popup from './Popup';

class PostPopup extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isChecked: false,
    };

    this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
  }

  (...)

  handleCheck = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;

    if (target.checked) {
      this.setState({ isChecked: false });
      console.log(this.state.isChecked);
    } else {
      this.setState({ isChecked: true });
      console.log(this.state.isChecked);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Popup {...this.props} style="post-popup">
        <header>Post a new product</header>
        <section>
                <form>
                    
            (...)

            <div className="form-check">
              <input
                className="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                value=""
                id="checkRaffle"
                ref="checkRaffle"
                onChange={this.handleCheck}
              ></input>
              <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="checkRaffle">
                Lorem ipsum
              </label>
            </div>

            (...)

            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handlePost}>
              Envoyer
            </button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </Popup>
    );
  }
}

export default PostPopup;
```

Comment: State changes are asynchronous. You can't `console.log` then on the next line and see them as changed. Pinr `this.state.isChecked` at the top of the render function, as this is called *after* state has changed and will have updated state values

Comment: Totally makes sense... i should've think about this! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I console.log(this.state.isChecked); and the first 2 clicks return
> "false" in my console, i can't understand why... Then after that if i
> continue clicking it works fine and alternate true and false.

You need to `console` after the state is set, use `setState` callback for that. These 2nd param of `setState` is the callback which is executed after the state is set. Note that `setState` is asynchronous so the next line after `setState` is executed before `setState` call is complete.

This is what the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) say

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
> batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
> right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
> componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
> callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
> has been applied.

```
if (target.checked) {
  this.setState({ isChecked: false }, ()=> {
            console.log(this.state.isChecked);
    });
  
} else {
  this.setState({ isChecked: true }, ()=> {
            console.log(this.state.isChecked);
    });
}
```

Other way to console the check value is

```
handleCheck = (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  const value = target.value;

  console.log("isChecked: " , target.checked);
  ....
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your stated value back to the checkbox. And pass the checked status if anything changes.

```
<input
                className="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                checked={isChecked}
                id="checkRaffle"
                ref="checkRaffle"
                onChange={this.handleCheck}
              ></input>
```